# How to change the location of password box on Windows 7 logon screen?

Tags: windows-7, login-screen

I want to change my Windows logon screen background but the image shows exactly in the middle of the screen. So, I want to change the location of the password box to either side.

Is this possible and can anyone help me to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Then Hack the GUI dammit!! XD

http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/879070-windows-7-logon-editing-guide/

It's easy. I've managed to not only change the background, but also the positioning of the password field, the removal of the User Picture, and the Windows 7 Branding. I even toyed around with giving the ease of access button an executable string! (Start some program from Login - like CMD!! (Not recommended for shared computers)

You'll need a resource hacker. I'll be in the link I gave.

Have fun!

Comment: on first line you say `Open authui.dll located in C:\Windows\system32` but that is a binary file. wtf?

Comment: Yes. Also it has an icon if you change its extension to .exe O_o

Comment: authui.dll is a binary file, but not of the executable type that Jet speaks of (exe). It's a (dynamic) library link file. This usually means that the file is a form of software-level database that is used by the operating system, and usually for a specific purpose. In this case, the name does seem to identify its purpose: Authentication User Interface - otherwise known as the login screen :D